# Mistake in Program?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Link to incorrect submission : http://codeforces.com/contest/158/submission/6412916

Problem:

> "Contestant who earns a score equal to or greater than the k-th place
>   finisher's score will advance to the next round, as long as the
>   contestant earns a positive score..." — an excerpt from contest rules.
>
> A total of n participants took part in the contest (n ≥ k), and you
>   already know their scores. Calculate how many participants will
>   advance to the next round.
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line of the input contains two integers n and k
>   (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 50) separated by a single space.
>
> The second line contains n space-separated integers a1, a2, ..., an
>   (0 ≤ ai ≤ 100), where ai is the score earned by the participant who
>   got the i-th place. The given sequence is non-increasing (that is, for
>   all i from 1 to n - 1 the following condition is fulfilled:
>   ai ≥ ai + 1).
>
> ### Output
>
> Output the number of participants who advance to the next
>   round.

---

Program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int scores[101];

    for (int i=0; i<= k; i++) {

        cin>>scores[i];
    }

    int participants =0 ;
    int passingscore = scores[k-1];

    for (int l = 0; l<=n; l++) {             //check each item
        if (scores[l] >= passingscore) {      //check if l'th score is greater than the passing score
            participants+=1;
        }
    }

    if (scores[0] == 0){
        cout << 0;
    }
    else {
        cout<<participants;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT::
It now seems that i have a logical error (see: http://codeforces.com/contest/158/submission/6413415).

I cannot find it.

Update:  Found the mistakes! thanks for the help! 3rd program I've made!!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And did you realize the Codeforces interface actually tells you the failing test case? And if you had compiled your code with warnings and a decent compiler, it would tell you the problem with that code

Comment: When i compile it on my compiler, the output is 6

Comment: you only read k+1 scores, you need to read all n scores.  Then you iterate over n+1 elements to check the score.  This is a possible error when memory isn't cleared which might be the case with the test compiler?  I.e. when you read the values `10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5` you have an array with 101 elements, `10 9 8 7 7 7 X X X X X ...`.  You don't know what is in those X spots, yet your loop iterates over the first THREE Xs since you're using `<=n` in your loop.  Also you should break from that loop if you see a zero, I don't know why you would check `scores[0]` for a zero value...+

Answer (score 3):

As Niklas suggests, your compiler should provide warnings hinting at to what you are doing wrong. I've included the output from clang, which I feel is pretty readable.

```
[3:27pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang++ -Wall foo.cc
foo.cc:20:13: warning: variable 'participants' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
            participants+=1;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cc:15:21: note: initialize the variable 'participants' to silence this warning
    int participants ;
                    ^
                     = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Not fixing this invokes undefined behavior. So two different compilers (or runs) could come up with different results.